# How to indicate that a column in a table is sortable (UI design question)?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, ui-design, gui-design

In the application that I am working on, there is tabular data (for the record, it is a Java Swing app using `JTables`). In some cases the data is sortable by clicking on the column headers.
What I want to know is what is a good way to indicate to the user if a given column is sortable or not?

I have come up with the following possibilities.

1) Put an icon in each sortable column indicating it is sortable. I personally do not like this option.

2) Change the mouse cursor into something else when it hovers over the header to indicate it is sortable.

3) Put a note in the tooltip text when hovering over the column saying that it is sortable.

Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Update:

I think a clarification is in order.
My question is **not** how does one indicate that a given column is **currently** sorted. That is already implemented via the up/down sort triangle paradigm.
I want to give the user a clue as to which columns **can** be sorted before they click on the header to sort it.

Update 2:
I think I should explain why I'm not entirely sold on option #1. It seems to me that if one is going to put an icon to indicate which columns **are** sortable then this will add to visual clutter. In such cases, sometimes the UI changes on "mouse over". Case in point: Windows Vista and 7 allows one to add a filter on a column yet the indicator for this does not appear until you hover over the header with the mouse.

Comment: Is response to update 2, couldn't you do option 1 on mouse-over? It seems like a reasonable thing to do, although it's still not super great since the user has to accidentally mouse-over to find it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you're dealing with the UI, you have to put your mind into what the user will expect.  I would almost always recommend staying with the paradigms that your users will expect. Therefore  I would recommend a version of option 1)

[RememberME's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375373/how-to-indicate-that-a-column-in-a-table-is-sortable-ui-design-question/2375396#2375396) post describes how this could work - You can still use arrows in column headers - one option would be to put an arrow icon in the header, but change the state of that icon if it was sorted (e.g. highlight the up or down button if the dataset is currently sorted by this column.)

**Edit:**
A Windows Explorer example may not be the best example here. My original text quoted below:

> In Windows Explorer and almost all
>   form datagrids there is a small icon,
>   usually an up or down arrow, that
>   indicates that a column is sortable.
>   Experiment with Windows Explorer to
>   see the way in which this works.

Comment: See my clarification. Windows Explorer only puts an icon in the currently sorted column. Unlike my app though, **every** column in Windows Explorer is sortable.

Comment: @Avrom - You can still use arrows in column headers - one option would be to put an arrow icon in the header, but change the state of that icon if it was sorted (e.g. highlight the up or down button if you are currently sorted by this), like in RememberMe's post

Comment: Though he didn't mention it explicitly, I believe the posted screenshot is an excellent way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

In many apps, triangles indicate sortable so I think that's the best way to convey the information to the user b/c it's a standard they're most likely familiar with.

I think the jquery plugin from [DataTables.Net](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html) is a good example.  You could take a look and see if you like the look/functionality of that and emulate it.  Both an up and a down indicate sortable.  Just one or the other indicate that it is being sorted. If they column is not sortable, there is no icon at all.  Their example also changes the pointer from an arrow to the hand pointer to indicate that you can click on the header.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the standard way is essentially option 1: either display the data initially sorted with a little arrow pointing either up or down (ascending/descending), or sort+display the icon as soon as the column header is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I think having a little arrow or triangle icon below the column heading, which you can click to sort by that column is the best option, as it is easy to see visually and very intuitive to use.

Answer (score 0):

Little triangular up/down sort icons are pretty much standard for sortable table views in desktop applications and web pages. You may not like them, but your users are probably used to them (even if they don't realize it).

You should of course change the mouse cursor over clickable elements.

Answer (score 0):

You should always do 2 for anything clickable.

Number 1 is not bad, typically a triangle pointing up or down depending on the sort order.

To indicate clickability, you could also use blue, underlined text on sortable columns and plain dark gray text on nonsortables -- the http link appearance is a well-known device to virtually all users, but it would not convey sortability, per se. Rather, a user might expect clicking that to take them to some other screen or list, as a hyperlink typically does.

Comment: I am curious why you and others are recommending changing the cursor. To me, this seems like an outdated technique, and I cannot think of any cases of it being used that I have seen recently.

Comment: I am already using a v and ^ icon to indicate which column is currently sorted (primary sort). That is a different concept than which columns are sortable to begin with.

Comment: Chris, the mouse cursor changes on click-able elements of this page.

Avrom, see my response about the carets/triangles for sortable vs. sorted.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. I meant for my question to be in the context of column headers (which in Avron's case I am guessing are not part of a webpage), not 'anything clickable'.

Comment: No, I'm sorry.  I thought it was a web app.

Answer (score -2):

I may be a little dense, but what kinds of columns are *not* sortable?

Pretty much anything can be sorted; even if there is no strict "greater than" relationship, at least there will be an "equals", and then sorting simply means "bring equal things together".

Strings? Try alphabetical ordering. Images? Sort by percentage of red, green, blue (or if you want to get fancy, compare color histograms). Locations? Use distance to Rome or any other arbitrary location.

Sorting on some columns may be much more useful than sorting on others; but I have a hard time finding a column type were it is important to *avoid* sorting from taking place.

Comment: There's a difference between *can* be sorted vs. "dealing with an already implemented application with dozens of tables in which some columns are sortable and some are not and to simply change it is not currently an option".

Comment: And I was just pointing out that you have a 4th option: implement a small generic equality-based sorter, and use it for all your currently unsortable "does not implement Comparable" columns. That way users get what they expect when they click on the column header.

The amount of code needed for this is comparable to what you will need to add to implement options 1. + 2., and the end result is, in my opinion, much more user-friendly. But hey, its your party.